# Are other browsers affected by browser specific header?

Tags: http-headers, internet-explorer-9

I am having an issue with IE 9 setting itself into "Quirks mode" automatically. To combat this I came across another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567661/http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-chrome-1-putting-this-in-hta) where an answer suggested that the following header be added (via web.config) to force IE 9 into "Standards mode".

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```

This indeed worked in that IE 9 rendered the page in "Standards mode". What I am wondering is, by adding this header will other browsers be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `X-UA-Compatible` is an IE-specific header as far as I am aware. Note that `chrome=1` is not a flag for the Chrome browser, but for *really* old versions of IE (think IE6, IE7) to use the Google Chrome Frame add-on, which itself is [now obsolete](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html).

Comment: Do you think the `chrome=1` can be safely omitted? Should it be omitted?

Comment: @webworm: Considering that it will soon be a year since the plugin was retired, it should be safe to omit it.