# @viewport tag in CSS not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

For various reasons I can't modify any HTML for the project I'm working on. So I can't set this attribute:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I've tried putting this in my CSS:

```
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Testing on an iPhone it still renders the wrong breakpoints. I take it this feature hasn't made its way into browsers yet?

If it's not possible to do in CSS, can I set this in a server side header? e.g. for IE I put `X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1` in the Apache response header. Is it possible to do the same with the viewport tag?

Answer (score 1):

May be you need vendor prefixes:

```
@-wekbit-viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
}
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
}
@-o-viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
}
@viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Note: Currently firefox and safari doesn't support @viewport css.

See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport) for more info.

[Using server side technology,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567661/http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-chrome-1-putting-this-in-hta)

You could add it to your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Right, not implemented on Safari mobile. So if the CSS solution doesn't work, is there a server side solution?